# PowerEdge R710 System Configuration using SN

Tags: linux, dell-poweredge

i have got Dell PowerEdge R710 server with Linux OS. And i have the serial number for the server .any one can guide me in easy way to know the configuration system for my server ?
Thanks..

Comment: Shouldn't you ask Dell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pop your service tag into the [Dell support site](http://www.dell.com/support/home/au/en/audhs1), and you will be able to see what that server *left the factory* with.

To see what it has *now*, you will need to log onto the iDrac interface and view the hardware inventory in there. You can either log in via its web interface (you can get the IP address from the front-panel LCD of the server), or you can interface with it via [`racadm`](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/3205.racadm-command-line-interface-for-drac).

Comment: i have already insert the serves tag. and i got the system configuration but each component  shows only the part number, amount and the description. do i need to search for each part number for each component?

Comment: What more do you need other than the part number, description, and quantity?